# Adding an ImageView to a Constraint Layout causes a crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a splash screen for my app and it works just fine when I only display some text on the splashScreen's layout file(using a Constraint Layout). When I add an imageView however, the app crashes and I don't get why. The image's file size is only 299kb so it's not a memory issue or something right? Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it? Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreen">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="377dp"
    android:layout_height="293dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
package com.spdesigns.funfacts;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int Splash_Timer = 4000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,FunFactsActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainActivity);
            finish();
        }
    },Splash_Timer);
}
}
```

Logcat Error:

```
11-15 18:29:19.218 3486-3486/com.spdesigns.funfacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.spdesigns.funfacts, PID: 3486
                                                                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 655089132 byte allocation with 3077156 free bytes and 379MB until OOM
                                                                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
                                                                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
                                                                      at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
                                                                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                      at com.spdesigns.funfacts.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:15)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: sadly this is not the cause of the problem :(

Comment: just updated the post, this outOfMemory has happened to me in the past with splashScreens. Why is this? I'm only using small size images in my splashScreen

Comment: Do you have this issue in all devices? Do you have the logo drawable for each resolution? Could specify the size in pixel, in mb and the format of the image? Have you tried use AppCompatImageView instead of ImageView?

Comment: No, I just use one resolution :( . 6960x3415 size in pixels (didn't expect that) / 299 KB and it's a PNG file

Comment: try to keep it into 2048xYYY

Comment: thank you very much this worked. May I know why that is? I guess such a high resolution required a lot of memory and android studio can't allocate so much memory?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that ImageView uses a GL Texture, which on most devices is limited to 2048x2048. The max texture size varies from device to device, I've seen is as small as ~1500x1500 and as big as 4096x4096.

For that, you have to create an image for each dimension to make sure will work in all devices. Check this thread for more info.

[GL Maximum Textures Size Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380635/gl-maximum-textures-size-policy)